# Use ref to invoke instance methods

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using the [react-native-drawer-menu](https://github.com/Tinysymphony/react-native-drawer-menu) to create a slider menu. I am not able to open the menu manually when a button is clicked. In the documentation they said that this could be done by using the ref to invoke instance the methods `openDrawer`.

this is my code

```
import Drawer from 'react-native-drawer-menu'

  myFunction(){
    Drawer.openDrawer();
  }
```

and I get this error

> reactNativeDrawerMenu2.default.openDrawer is not a function. (In
>   '_reactNativeDrawerMenu2.default.openDrawer()',
>   '_reactNativeDrawerMenu2.default.openDrawer' is undefined) 2017-10-17
>   13:16:24.299 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue]
>   Unhandled JS Exception: _reactNativeDrawerMenu2.default.openDrawer is
>   not a function. (In '_reactNativeDrawerMenu2.default.openDrawer()',
>   '_reactNativeDrawerMenu2.default.openDrawer' is undefined)

Comment: React documentation for using [Refs and the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the ref ("reference") to the drawer. I think it should be

```
import Drawer from 'react-native-drawer-menu'

class Foo extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Drawer ref={drawer => this.drawer = drawer}>
        <View>
          <Button onPress={() => this.drawer.open()}
        </View>
      </Drawer>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @lipp said, except this is the [API](https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer#opening--closing-the-drawer-programmatically) of the module:

So it becomes:

```
<Drawer ref={(node) => {this.drawer = node;}} />
```

and then you can use their API like:

> this.drawer.open()